# r: creating normalized variable as new variable

Tags: r, function, sapply

I'm looking to create a normalized version of a variable in my dataframe (`df$var`). I want to use `sapply` and a primary function, but it returns `1` on all counts:

```
df<- data_frame(var= c(1:10))
df$varMean<- mean(df$var)
df$varNorm<- sapply(df$var,function(x){x/mean(x)})

> df$varNorm
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

How can I generate the normalized value of `df$var` in each row?

Comment: you know you can just do `seq_along(df$var)`. You **have** to use `sapply` ?

Comment: apologies: i edited the question to be more clear as i'm not looking for an index, i'm trying to create a normalized version of my variable and add it to the data frame. hope this clears that up.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: let me know if that works.

Comment: you haven't shared your expected output. Anyway, do you need `df$var/mean(df$var)` ?

Comment: yes. it appears i overcomplicated this. this worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
df$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df))
```

this will create index  for your df